# How to disable the console cursor from moving automatically

Tags: winapi, console-application, kernel32

**Situation:**

I am crating an console application for windows using rust. Fore that I use `winapi` and `kernel32`.

Lets say my cursor position within the console is at `4,4 (X,Y)` then I print an character like `print!("@");` at position `4,4`. Then the console automatically moves the cursor one to the right `5,4` for the next character to be printed there.

**Question**

Is it possible to prevent this default behavior, and have the cursor stay at `4,4` instead of moving to the next cell, using`winapi/kernel32`? What I mean by that is that the console should not change cursor position in any case until I manually tell the console to change the cursor position to another cell.

*Example or solution maybe in any language.*

Comment: you can use [`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) - *has no effect on the cursor position.*

Comment: Thanks, is it also posible to put the console in an certain mode (described above). So I do not need to call that function every time. Why, because I manualy handle the cursor position.

Comment: `SetConsoleCursorPosition`

Comment: Thanks maybe a misunderstanding I did not describe it clear what I meant. I want to put the console in an certain mode so it will not move the cursor until I manually change the cursor position.

Comment: It's not clear what the value of such a mode would be. `print("hello")` would just print all the letters on top of each other, leaving just `o`. If you want to print without moving the cursor, then use `WriteConsoleOutput`.

Comment: Thanks, I need it for a certain thing it is a little odd but if it cannot be done I'll go with WriteConsoleOutput

Comment: If for some reason you can't use `WriteConsoleOutput`: Get the current cursor position ([`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo)). Call `printf` or whatever. Restore the cursor position ([`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but WriteConsoleOutput will do it.

Comment: The only related console screen-buffer mode is `ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT`. If this is disabled, the console overwrites characters when the cursor is at the end of the line instead of advancing to the next line and scrolling.